# Hide table row not working with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

Why it is not working?

jQuery code:

```
 $("table.test #ro").hide();
```

HTML:

```
    <table class="test">
  <thead><tr class="ro"  id='ro' ><th>test</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr class="ro"><td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr><td>test</td>
  </tr></tbody>
  </table>
```

I tried it in different manner; `.hide()` and `.css('display', 'none')` are not working

Comment: try $("table.test > #ro").hide();

Comment: I don't see anything wrong here. Does your console show any errors?

Comment: Didn't you forget to place the code inside `$(document).ready(function() { ... });`?

Comment: As IDs must be unique, `$("table.test #ro")` isn't necessary. `$("#ro")` will suffice.

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/sacx8/

Comment: jsFiddle automatically wraps the code in the document load event.

Comment: @FábioSantos Depends on the settings.

Comment: @VisioN That's why I said "automatically". Edit: I meant "by default", actually.

Comment: yeah it's inside $(document).ready..

Comment: it worked just when i put the script in the end of the page !

Comment: @fatiDev as you can see by Claudio's fiddle the code works. Do you have other code that may be interfering? Can you reproduce this on jsFiddle?

Comment: no , it's ok now with the script at the end of the page

Comment: @fatiDev You may have accidentally included your script before jQuery.

Comment: not before jquery , but at the top of the page before the table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to wait for document to get ready, using `$(document).ready(` event. You can access direct with id as id is supposed to be unique, instead of making complex selector.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/vQSY7/1/)**

```
$(document).ready(function(){        
    $("#ro").hide();
});
```

This is `also working` which you have in question, I think you need to put it in `$(document).ready(`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){        
     $("table.test #ro").hide();
});
```

​